# GA4 data not available in Google Ads

Tags: google-ads-api, google-analytics-4

We have been running GA4 and Google Ads on our website for a while now. However, the GA4 data appears not to be available in Google Ads even though the accounts are linked. For example, we can see 'All user' data in GA4, but the automatically imported GA4 audience 'All users' is not being filled (it does have some users, but that is probably from when we use UA). I have installed the GA4 tag through GTM, and it is working as GA4 data gets filled.

GA4: [Linked account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsOrO.png)

GA4: [All users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOWFy.png)

GAds: [GA4 All users in Ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Sf3.png)

I have cross checked all links, property codes etc and all do match with the corresponding account, but unfortunately the data is not being imported. Also, when I create a new audience in GA4, the data is not available in Google Ads. When I configure the Google Ads remarketing/conversion tag in our GTM, the audience does get filled.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I fixed it.

You have to login to your google analytics.

Click on Admin at the bottom left hand corner, you will then see Data settings. Under Data settings, you will see data collection. In that page, you will have to activate Google signals data collection and also Acknowledge the User Data Collection Acknowledgement.

I have attached a screen shot for your reference.

Once you do this, you will be able to see the data for audiences in google ads from your google analytics property. It can take upto 24 hours for the data to be visible in your google ads audiences.

I hope my answer helps you!

Best Regards,
Shoaib Hussain

Images are below

[Data collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RwYh.png)

[Google signals data collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLASB.png)

[User Data Collection Acknowledgement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCwGX.png)

Comment: Do you know since when that was needed to have your data synced by GA4 and Google Ads?

My audience in Google ads was working for 2 years and went to 0 before lets say half a year.