# GA4 user data not available as column in Google Ads

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I'm using Google Analytics to add data to the corresponding and connected Google Ads campaign, visible in the Googla Ads backend.

Connecting Analytics UA with Google Ads worked fine, but the user data delivered by GA4 does not appear in Google Ads.

I connected the new GA4 account with the matching Google Ads account.

The data, that should appear as columns in the Ads campaign data, can be found in the settings for the columns. Go to "Campaigns", then "Columns" - Modify columns - Google Analytics.

Here should appear "% Engaged sessions (GA4)", "Events/session (GA4)", "Avg. session duration (seconds) (GA4)".

In some cases it does, but mostly not. (2 out of 6 it works)

[image: Columns settings with GA4 metrics]

[image: Columns settings without GA4 metrics]

I tried to find differences or similarities to get to the bottom of the problem. Although some of the installations are using GTM and some are not the ones with the problem do not correlate to the one with or without GTM.

Settings and connection in Google Ads and GA4 should be similar as far as I can see. GA4 accounts are listed under the "tools and settings" - "setup" - "linked accounts" in Google Ads.

In "Google Analytics (GA4) & Firebase" - "Manage & Link" I can see a difference in the columns. The accounts with the correct data have the entry "Linked: App and web metrics activated" in Status and an extra column "Apps and web metrics", where it says "Deactivate".

[image: Linked account with GA4 metrics]

[image: Linked account without GA4 metrics]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I am fairly sure what the solution is now.
Looking at this post - [GA4 data not available in Google Ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70752298/ga4-data-not-available-in-google-ads)
I didn't enable Google Signals, but did everything under 'user data collection'.
I waited 24 hours.
It didn't work.
I waited 48 hours.
It did work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Google fixed the problem. Today I could activate the "App and web metrics" in all Google Ads with connected GA4 via the Linked Accounts - Google Analytics (GA4) & Firebase settings.